# Making HEVC Files

Tags: ipad, icloud, video, h.265

What settings do I need to use to make HEVC video in Handbrake?
I encoded a h.265 video and it will not play on my new iPad(5th Generation)

I am trying to open them in the iOS 11 files app.

Comment: Hey Matt, first of all welcome to Ask Different! :) If Matt Sephton's answer doesn't help you, could I suggest you [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/319596/edit) your question to include the actual settings you've tried so far? Also, it may be good to indicate whether you're open to using other software. Finally, (yeah I know, lots of suggestions), it's probably a good idea to indicate what software you were trying to view the video with on your iPad?

Comment: Hi Matt, if you happened to get two accounts, you can use the contact us link below to get things merged. If it’s two Matt - forgive the suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

Handbrake is probably not the best choice for this as it's so unfriendly and difficult to setup. The easiest way I've found is:

1. Select one of the *Matroska H.265 Presets*
2. Change *Summary > Format* to *MP4 File*
3. *Start* encoding

The only issue is if your source video does not match one of the presets.

[image]

You might have more luck, and make your life easier with [Half app](http://www.halfapp.co) ($9.99).

Apple's Compressor app ([App Store link](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/compressor/id424390742?mt=12), not available for free) can do this easily: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208238

1. Select the setting in the batch area,
2. Click Video in the Inspector, then click Change.
3. Click the Compression Type pop-up, then choose HEVC from the list.

Using Compressor [you can also create a self-contained HEVC droplet](https://help.apple.com/compressor/mac/4.4/#/cpsr8747db7f) for easy drag-and-drop encoding.